# XMLStarlet: Printing one line per item, while using datum from parent element

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have XML data formatted in this fashion:

```
<XML>
    <Waveforms Time="01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM">
        <WaveformData Channel="I">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 </WaveformData>
        <WaveformData Channel="II">9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 </WaveformData>
    </Waveforms>
    <Waveforms Time="01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM">
        <WaveformData Channel="I">1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 </WaveformData>
        <WaveformData Channel="II">9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 </WaveformData>
    </Waveforms>
</XML>
```

I am trying to use xmlstarlet to parse this data to a text file (comma delimited).  The desired output would look like this:

```
Time Attribute, Channel Attribute, Data
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM, I, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM, II, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM, I, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM, II, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
```

The best I can come up with is:

```
 xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m //XML/Waveforms -v @Time -o "," -m Waves -v WaveformData/@Channel -o "," -v WaveformData -o "," -b -n testwave2.xml > testwave.txt
```

Which gives a result like this:

```
 01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM, I, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, II, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
 01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM, I, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, II, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
```

It's clear how to print one line per Waveforms, but not how to print one line per WaveformData if I want to include the time attribute from its parent. Can this be done? Alternately, should I work around and do some slicing and pasting to fix it on the back end afterwards?

Comment: The proposed command line in this question and test data in this question don't actually work together. Perhaps the elided `Waves` is at fault?

Comment: ...at the moment, I worry that any answer I generated wouldn't work against your *actual* data.

Comment: It seems I pasted a spin off of the code I used to generate the output above.  I think the only difference is the -m waves is removed, but won't be able to check until tomorrow.  The real question is simply how to get the time to parse with every set of waveform data.

Comment: The actual data is in the format above, the xmlstarlet code is just off a bit.

Comment: Aside: `//XML` is asking the parser to search through the document for `XML` elements. Unless you know you need to do that, use `/XML`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for the WaveformData -- given as it's what you want one line per each of -- and just traverse upwards in the tree to find your time element.

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /XML/Waveforms/WaveformData \
     -v ../@Time -o "," \
     -v @Channel -o "," \
     -v . -n <in.xml
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM,I,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM,II,9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 
01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM,I,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 
01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM,II,9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
```

Alternately, if you *know* that each Waveforms will have exactly two WaveformData children, you could do the following:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /XML/Waveforms \
    -v ./@Time -o ",I,"  -v './WaveformData[@Channel="I"]' -n \
    -v ./@Time -o ",II," -v './WaveformData[@Channel="II"]' -n <in.xml
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM,I,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM,II,9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM,I,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM,II,9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll test this out tomorrow!

Comment: What's the purpose of the . after the third -v??

Comment: @TomFogarty - it's the current context; in this case `WaveformData`.

Comment: Thanks Charles - Great solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer daniel

Answer (score 4):

To give a slight variation of Charles Duffy's answer, you could use the `concat()` function to simplify it a bit, and an initial template to provide the CSV header:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel \
    -t -o 'Time Attribute, Channel Attribute, Data' -n \
    -t -m '//Waveforms/WaveformData' \
       -v 'concat(../@Time, ", ", @Channel, ", ", text())' -n \
  waveforms.xml
Time Attribute, Channel Attribute, Data
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM, I, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
01/01/2009 3:00:02 AM, II, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM, I, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
01/01/2009 3:00:04 AM, II, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4
```